# set of $Ф$ as $\{ \}$ proof of uniqueness

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

The following set:
$S = \{Ф, \{Ф\}, \{Ф, \{Ф\}\}\}$
can be represented by the following string (finite sequence) of “$\{$” and “$\}$”:
$s = \{ \{ \} \{ \{ \} \} \{ \{ \} \{ \{ \} \} \} \}$
Note that the empty set $Ф$ was written as $\{ \}$ and all commas were omitted.
$1)$ Show that if a string s of “$\{$“ and “$\}$” represents a set $S$, then $S$ is unique, i.e. two different sets are represented by two different strings.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** From a (suitable) string of $\{$s and $\}$s, you can recover the expression a finite set written in list notation by first replacing all instances of "$\}\{$" by "$\},\{$", and then replacing all instances of "$\{\}$" by "$\varnothing$". Now use the fact that two sets are equal if and only if they contain the same elements.